# date conversion DD-MMM-YY to YYYYMMDD

Tags: date, ksh, aix

How to convert DD-MMM-YY to YYYYMMDD

I am in AIX, using korn shell.

neither `date --date` nor `date -d` works in aix.

Comment: Are you wanting to convert an arbitrary date?   Or 'now'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in perl, the hard way

```
sub formatDate_YYYYMMDD 
{
my $date=shift;
my ($day,$mon,$yr) = split /\-/,$date;
my @months=qw(JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC );
$i=0;
foreach $_ (@months)
    {
        $i++; 
        if (/$mon/i){$mon=$i;}
    }
$year=2000+$yr;
$mon=sprintf "%02d",$mon;
print "Invalid month format $date present in $file_name" if $mon ==0;
return("$year$mon$day");
}
```

Comment: my indentation got swallowed :(

Answer (score 2):

pure ksh:

```sh
convert_date () {
  typeset -l date=$1
  typeset IFS="-"
  set -- $date  # now $1 is the day, $2 is the lower-case month, $3 is the year

  typeset months
  set -A months "" jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec
  typeset -i m=1

  while [[ $m -le 12 ]]; do 
    if [[ "$2" = "${months[$m]}" ]]; then 
      break
    else
      m=$(( m+1 ))
    fi
  done

  # assume this century
  printf "20%02d%02d%02d\n" "$3" $m "$1"
}

convert_date 06-JUL-11   # ==> 20110706
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `tclsh` on your system:

```
old="06-JUL-11"
new=$( echo "puts [clock format [clock scan $old] -format %Y%m%d]" | tclsh )
echo $new   # ==> 20110706
```